# Scroll bar issues with cross platform web browsers

Tags: gwt, cross-browser

scroll bar issues with cross platform browsers
a web app developed in Goolge web toolkit is having scroll panel issues in mac. where should i start working on to fix the issue. i am confused is that specific to one system or generic

Comment: Faced this issue myself, try creating browser specific CSS to solve the issue. Hope that this helps!

Comment: Can you give us more detail? For example are you using a scroll panel? How are you setting the sizes of the panels? What type of panels are you using...